# how to use struts form fields (s:textfield, s:password) and style them using materializecss framework?

Tags: jsp, struts2, materialize

```
<form class = "col l12 s12">
    <div class = "row">
        <div class="input-field col l6 s6">
            <input id="firstName" type="text" class="validate">
            <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I want to apply Struts2 on the above code to get the value of `firstName`. How should i do that?

EDIT (whole jsp code for registration form):

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>

<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
<head>
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Import materialize.css-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/register.css">
    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>

<body>
    <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <div class = "background">
        <h1 class = "center-align white-text">Register</h1>
    </div>
    <div class = "container formContainer white z-depth-2">
        <div class = "row formParent">
            <form class = "col l12 s12">
                <div class = "row">
                    <div class="input-field col l6 s6">
                        <input id="firstName" type="text" class="validate">
                        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field col l6 s6">
                        <input id="lastName" type="text" class="validate">
                        <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class = "row">
                    <div class="input-field col l12 s12">
                        <input id="username" type="text" class="validate">
                        <label for="username">Username</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class = "row">
                    <div class="input-field col s6">
                        <input id="password" type="password" class="validate">
                        <label for="password">Enter password</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field col s6">
                        <input id="repeatPassword" type="password" class="validate">
                        <label for="repeatPassword">Repeat password</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <input id="email" type="email" class="validate">
                        <label for="email" data-error="wrong" data-success="right">Email</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class = "row formButtons">
                    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light right submitButton purple accent-4" type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
                    <a href = 'index.jsp' class = 'btn waves-effect waves-dark right cancelButton purple accent-1'>Cancel</a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

In the above jsp code, i wish to get the field values and i want to be able to assign them to the following actionClass:

```
public class registerAction {
    private String firstName, lastName, username;
    public String execute(){
        return "";
    }
}
```

but i dont know how to apply the struts prefix to the jsp form which is using materialize css input fields.

Here is the code for struts.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration    2.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"/>
    <package name="helloWorld" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="hello" class = "com.bugManager.registerAction"   method="execute">
        <result name="success">helloWorld.jsp</result>
    </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

Comment: Where do you want to get the value and how did you do that?

Comment: i want to get the value of firstName and use it in the Actionclass for storage in a database.

Comment: What actionclass, how many actionclasses do you have, how doyou submit the form?

Comment: i want to get the value of firstName and use it in the Actionclass for storage in a database. The above was the code snippet from register.jsp where a user is registering. I havent added the form action because i dont know how to take the field values with struts prefix ( like  s:textarea but instead of textarea, using the form tags of materializecss).

Comment: please see the updated question now.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @RomanC I've edited the question title, hope this makes it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i did it on my own. If someone wants to use materializecss form tags in struts2 do the following:

**1. Add this line into the struts.xml**

```
<constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" />
```

my updated and working **struts.xml**

```
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"/>
    <constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" /> <!-- this is the line which helps in applying materializecss's styling to the form elements -->
    <package name="com.bugManager" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="register" class = "com.bugManager.registerAction" method="execute">
            <result name="success">helloWorld.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

my **helloWorld.jsp:** (any redirection page, i made this page to test out if the values are being mapped and stored correctly)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World Strut</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello from <s:property value = "firstName"/> <s:property value = "lastName"/> <s:property value = "username"/> <s:property value = "password"/>
         <s:property value="email"/>

    </body>
</html>
```

**2. Then change**

**Form tags**

```
<form></form> to <s:form></s:form>
```

**any text or email input tags to**

```
<s:textfield />
```

**password fields to**

```
<s:password />
```

**submit can remain the same.**

**Check out the example form code given below**

```
<s:form class = "col l12 s12" action = "register">
    <div class = "row">
        <div class="input-field col l6 s6">

            <s:textfield name = "firstName" id="firstName" type="text" class="validate"/>
            <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col l6 s6">
            <s:textfield name = "lastName" id="lastName" type="text" class="validate"/>
            <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "row">
        <div class="input-field col l12 s12">
            <s:textfield name = "username" id="username" type="text" class="validate"/>
            <label for="username">Username</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
            <s:password name = "password" id="password" type="password" class="validate"/>
            <label for="password">Enter password</label>
        </div>
        <div class = 'input-field col s6'>
            <s:password name = "password" id="repeatPassword" type="password" class="validate"/>
            <label for="repeatPassword">Repeat password</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <s:textfield name = "email" id="email" type="email"/>
            <label for="email">Email</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "row formButtons">
        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light right submitButton purple accent-4" type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
        <a href = 'index.jsp' class = 'btn waves-effect waves-dark right cancelButton purple accent-1'>Cancel</a>
    </div>
</s:form>
```

**Take a look at all the struts form tags here:** http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_form_tags.htm

I hope this helps everyone who is trying to implement materializecss in Struts2!

Comment: This is a working example of my code, I don't think there's something wrong with my code. I couldn't use materializecss directly with struts to assign user inputs(text fields and password fields) to java class variables, so I tried by adding theme: simple in struts.xml. Now I can use materialize CSS and assign the user inputs to java class variables.